# Out of Range but it works, Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection

Tags: c#, .net, blazor-server-side

[image]So I was going through other threads trying to figure out why I am getting this error when I initially do this call for the sample data information. I click on the first button smooth, second button, smoothed then I click on sample data and I get this error. However, it actually is working in MongoDB how would I avoid this error because it is not really out of range if I created the categories etc.. before hand. I have searched many answers to do this but they really are out of range mine is not.

```cs
 at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.get_Item(Int32 index)
   at SuggestionAppWithTimCoreyUI.Pages.SampleData.GenerateSampleData() in D:\dotNet\SuggestionAppWithTimCoreyAPP\SuggestionAppWithTimCoreyUI\Pages\SampleData.razor:line 53
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallStateHasChangedOnAsyncCompletion(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask(Task taskToHandle, ComponentState owningComponentState)
```

```cs
// the code
@page "/SampleData"
@inject ICategoryData categoryData
@inject IStatusData statusData
@inject IUserData userData
@inject ISuggestionData suggestionData


<h3>Sample Data</h3>
@if (categoriesCreated)
{
    <h4>Categories have been created</h4>
}
else
{
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="CreateCategories">Create Categories </button>
}

@if (statusesCreated)
{
    <h4>Statuses have been created</h4>
}
else
{
    <button class="btn btn-info" @onclick="CreateStatuses">Create Statuses </button>
}
<button class="btn btn-dark" @onclick="GenerateSampleData">Sample Data</button>

@code {
    private bool categoriesCreated = false;
    private bool statusesCreated = false;

    private async Task GenerateSampleData()
    {
        UserModel user = new()
            {
                FirstName = "Tim",
                LastName = "Corey",
                EmailAddress = "tim@test.com",
                DisplayName = "Sample Tim Corey",
                ObjectIdentifier = "abc-123"
            };
        await userData.CreateUser(user);

        var foundUser = await userData.GetUserFromAuthentication("abc-123");
        var categories = await categoryData.GetAllCategories();
        var statuses = await statusData.GetAllStatuses();

        HashSet<string> votes = new();
        votes.Add("1");
        votes.Add("2");
        votes.Add("3");

        SuggestionModel suggestion = new()
            {
                Author = new BasicUserModel(foundUser),
                Category = categories[0],
                Suggestion = "Our First Suggestion",
                Description = "This is a suggestion created by the sample data generation method."
            };
        await suggestionData.CreateSuggestion(suggestion);

        suggestion = new()
            {
                Author = new BasicUserModel(foundUser),
                Category = categories[1],
                Suggestion = "Our Second Suggestion",
                Description = "This is a suggestion created by the sample data generation method.",
                SuggestionStatus = statuses[0],
                OwnerNotes = "This is the note for the status."
            };
        await suggestionData.CreateSuggestion(suggestion);

        suggestion = new()
            {
                Author = new BasicUserModel(foundUser),
                Category = categories[2],
                Suggestion = "Our Third Suggestion",
                Description = "This is a suggestion created by the sample data generation method.",
                SuggestionStatus = statuses[1],
                OwnerNotes = "This is the note for the status."
            };
        await suggestionData.CreateSuggestion(suggestion);

        suggestion = new()
            {
                Author = new BasicUserModel(foundUser),
                Category = categories[3],
                Suggestion = "Our Fourth Suggestion",
                Description = "This is a suggestion created by the sample data generation method.",
                SuggestionStatus = statuses[2],
                UserVotes = votes,
                OwnerNotes = "This is the note for the status."
            };
        await suggestionData.CreateSuggestion(suggestion);

        votes.Add("4");

        suggestion = new()
            {
                Author = new BasicUserModel(foundUser),
                Category = categories[4],
                Suggestion = "Our Fifth Suggestion",
                Description = "This is a suggestion created by the sample data generation method.",
                SuggestionStatus = statuses[3],
                UserVotes = votes,
                OwnerNotes = "This is the note for the status."
            };
        await suggestionData.CreateSuggestion(suggestion);

    }

    private async Task CreateCategories()
    {
        var categories = await categoryData.GetAllCategories();

        if (categories?.Count > 0)
        {
            return;
        }

        CategoryModel cat = new()
            {
                CategoryName = "Courses",
                CategoryDescription = "Full paid courses."
            };
        await categoryData.CreateCategory(cat);

        cat = new()
            {
                CategoryName = "Dev Questions",
                CategoryDescription = "Advice on being a developer."
            };
        await categoryData.CreateCategory(cat);

        cat = new()
            {
                CategoryName = "In-Depth Tutorial",
                CategoryDescription = "A deep-dive video on how to use a topic."
            };
        await categoryData.CreateCategory(cat);

        cat = new()
            {
                CategoryName = "10-Minute Training",
                CategoryDescription = "A quick \"How do I use this?\" video."
            };
        await categoryData.CreateCategory(cat);

        cat = new()
            {
                CategoryName = "Other",
                CategoryDescription = "Not sure which category this fits in."
            };
        await categoryData.CreateCategory(cat);

        categoriesCreated = true;
    }

    private async Task CreateStatuses()
    {
        var statuses = await statusData.GetAllStatuses();

        if (statuses?.Count > 0)
        {
            return;
        }

        StatusModel stat = new()
            {
                StatusName = "Completed",
                StatusDescription = "The suggestion was accepted and the corresponding item was created."
            };
        await statusData.CreateStatuses(stat);

        stat = new()
            {
                StatusName = "Watching",
                StatusDescription = "The suggestion is interesting. We are watching to see how much interest there is in it."
            };
        await statusData.CreateStatuses(stat);

        stat = new()
            {
                StatusName = "Upcoming",
                StatusDescription = "The suggestion was accepted and it will be released soon."
            };
        await statusData.CreateStatuses(stat);

        stat = new()
            {
                StatusName = "Dismissed",
                StatusDescription = "The suggestion was not something that we are going to undertake."
            };
        await statusData.CreateStatuses(stat);

        statusesCreated = true;
    }
}
```

the getallcategories()

```cs
    private readonly IMemoryCache _cache;
    private readonly IMongoCollection<CategoryModel> _cattegories;
    private const string CacheName = "CategoryData";
    public MongoCategoryData(IDbConnection db, IMemoryCache cache)
    {
        _cache = cache;
        _cattegories = db.CategoryCollection;
    }

    public async Task<List<CategoryModel>> GetAllCategories()
    {
        var output = _cache.Get<List<CategoryModel>>(CacheName);
        if (output == null)
        {
            var results = await _cattegories.FindAsync(_ => true);
            output = results.ToList();

            _cache.Set(CacheName, output, TimeSpan.FromDays(1));
        }

        return output;
    }
```

Comment: It gives me where the error is as well but I have clicked it so it won't be out of range because it was already made

Comment: Most likely `categoryData.GetAllCategories()` doesn't return any data, but you haven't shown us that code. You haven't given us enough code to diagnose the issue.

Comment: I added the coded to get all categories @Enigmativity

Comment: I also added console.writeline(categories[0]) now I have that error there

Comment: I suspect that the `List<CategoryModel>` is empty (which is different from `null`) when it comes from your `GetAllCategories()` method.

Comment: that makes no sense because its there in the database even before i click sample data

Comment: There's nothing else that it could be a this point. Your code cannot return `null` and you're getting on `categories[0]`. The only option is that it's not null and it's empty. Try running `Console.WriteLine(categories.IsEmpty());` and see if it produces `True`.

Comment: i can't use `Console.WriteLine(categories.IsEmpty());`

Comment: says there is no definition for that

Comment: You need `using System.Linq;` for that. Just use `categories.Count` and it should show `0`.

Comment: I tried using `System.Linq` and `categories.Count` does show `0` so I don't know what i am doing wrong whith this

Comment: I will just continue on the tutorial because he adds categories and statuses then stops program and adds the sample data when I did it that way  I got no errors. Sorry I just went through it all again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As covered in the comments, it looks like you're not pulling anything from your database. It's not clear what your query is (presumably pull all), but maybe check that your connection string is actually pointing at the instance you think it is. Presumably it's connecting to something since it's not throwing, but it might be some local dummy instance.

Some other thoughts since you indicated you're learning this from a tutorial:

- When you pull data from your database, add some sanity checks lest you have the same issue with your statuses.
- Assuming your `BasicUserModel` assigns an id upon creation, you probably only want to do this once. Instead of creating a separate author for each entry, do this once at the top once you've pulled the `foundUser` and pass that variable into each each Author property.
- By my count, you make at least 17 calls to your database across your page. Look for a bulk insert statement and pass an list of your new values into it to minimize load and latency.
- For one, I would advise you use [TryGetValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.caching.memory.cacheextensions.trygetvalue?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0#microsoft-extensions-caching-memory-cacheextensions-trygetvalue-1(microsoft-extensions-caching-memory-imemorycache-system-object-0@)) on your _cache value since you can instead put something like:

```
public async Task<List<CategoryModel>> GetAllCategories()
  if (_cache.TryGetValue<List<CategoryModel>>(CacheName, out var results)) 
    return results;

  output = (await _cattegories.FindAsync(_ => true)).ToList();
  _cache.Set(CacheName, output, TimeSpan.FromDays(1));
  return output;
}
```

- If you've got a default value you can use for the categories, you can do something like:

```
SuggestionModel suggestion = new()
{
    Author = new BasicUserModel(foundUser),
    Category = categories[0] ?? "<your default value>", //If categories is null, use the default value instead
    Suggestion = "Our First Suggestion",
    Description = "This is a suggestion created by the sample data generation method."
};
```

- Finally, I don't see that you're using `votes` for anything, so consider dropping that.

Good luck!

Comment: honestly I spelled something wrong and it still built i was confused. Since it was on the frontend I messed up but your `public async Task<List<CategoryModel>> GetAllCategories()
  if (_cache.TryGetValue<List<CategoryModel>>(CacheName, out var results)) 
    return results;
` is awesome and helps